# How to make a popup with two links/choices - but not just OK or cancel - in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page which shows a user's records. The records are cached so the page shows quickly.

There is a big, obvious "Update My Records" button on the page as well. Clicking it fetches data from another server and could take a minute or so to update. That's why we use the cached version and ask the user to press the Update button if they need an update. It would slow down the user experience if the data needed to be refreshed *every time* the user visited the page, and it would interfere with other things users might want to do on their records page (download stuff, etc.)

The problem is people don't notice the update button, even though it's big and bright and has big letters explaining what it is. So they are constantly emailing us for help asking how they can see their latest records.

In our 10th attempt to make this more obvious we are thinking that an in-your-face popup with two choices: "Continue and immediately see your records" or "Update your records - this might take a few minutes" might help.

What's the best way to make such a popup so if they continue they just go on to the records page as usual, but if they update they go to the URL of the Update button instead?

I don't want to use a simple popup of this kind:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" />
```

which I use for a confirmation before a form submission elsewhere, because then people will click the "OK" most of the time, even though they don't need to update, and the result will basically be the same as if it updated with every page entry.

Basically, I just want something to draw attention to the Update feature and a popup like this is my next idea. I can use JavaScript, including Jquery, and CSS to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds more like a UX problem rather than a coding problem?

Maybe you want to post [here (on User Expereince)](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) and you'll likely get answers that solve your problem from the approach of "*why are my users missing my buttons in the first place*?", rather than "how can I make this button more obvious?"

**Edit:**

If you just want to display a modal dialog, since you're already using jquery you can also use [jqueryui's dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation). They even have an example with two buttons. In the callback for the 2 buttons, you can insert your custom code for the different behaviours:

```
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: "auto",
      width: 400,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Continue": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" ); //do nothing
        },
        "Update": function() {
          //go to update
        }
      }
    });
  } );
```

Comment: My question is a specific Javascript / HTML coding question I believe.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was looking for. I tried it on my page and it works perfectly.